# Move illustration on curved path

Tags: html, css

I need to move illustration image on a curved path like this.

[image]

I tried with transform: translateX but I relaized that will not help because it's showing direct movement. Here is my code.

```css
.sun-half-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.sun-half {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10.5%;
  top: 12%;
  left: 13.5%;
  animation: sun 5s linear infinite;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

.sun-half img {
  width: 100%;
}
            
@keyframes sun {
  from {
    transform: translateX(10px); 
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(500px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sun-half-wrapper">
  <div class="sun-half">
    <img src="http://www.freepngimg.com/download/sun/2-2-sun-high-quality-png.png" alt="logo" style="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Any solution? Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u2rh18cg/) How about using transform-origin property?

Comment: _“I tried with transform: translateX but I relaized that will not help because it's showing direct movement.”_ - well then combine it with a translation in the other direction as well …? Doing basic research such as  https://www.google.com/search?q=css+move+object+along+curved+path could have lead you to https://css-tricks.com/moving-along-a-curved-path-in-css-with-layered-animation/ already ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine two movments: the image move to the right and the container move up down:

```css
.sun-half-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height:80vh
}

.sun-half {
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  animation: sun 5s ease-in-out  infinite;

}

.sun-half img {
  animation: image 5s ease-in-out infinite;

}
            
@keyframes sun {
  0% {
    bottom:0; 
  }
  50% {
    bottom:80px;
  }
  100% {
    bottom:0px;
  }
}
@keyframes image {
  0% {
    margin-left:0; 
  }
  100% {
    margin-left:50%;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="sun-half-wrapper">
  <div class="sun-half">
    <img src="http://www.freepngimg.com/download/sun/2-2-sun-high-quality-png.png" alt="logo" width="80">
  </div>
</div>
```

Or something like this without `position:absolute` and by simply changing margin:

```css
.sun-half {
  animation: sun 5s ease-in-out  infinite;
  margin-top:20%;

}

.sun-half img {
  animation: image 5s ease-in-out infinite;

}
            
@keyframes sun {
  0% {
    margin-top:20%; 
  }
  50% {
    margin-top:5%;
  }
  100% {
    margin-top:20%;
  }
}
@keyframes image {
  0% {
    margin-left:0; 
  }
  100% {
    margin-left:50%;
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="sun-half-wrapper">
  <div class="sun-half">
    <img src="http://www.freepngimg.com/download/sun/2-2-sun-high-quality-png.png" alt="logo" width="80">
  </div>
</div>
```

We can optimize with transform:

```css
.sun-half-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height:80vh
}

.sun-half {
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  left:0;
  bottom:0;
  animation: sun 5s ease-in-out  infinite;

}

.sun-half img {
  animation: image 5s ease-in-out infinite;

}
            
@keyframes sun {
  50% {
    transform:translateY(-80px);
  }
}
@keyframes image {
  100% {
    transform:translate(50vw);
  }

}
```

```html
<div class="sun-half-wrapper">
  <div class="sun-half">
    <img src="http://www.freepngimg.com/download/sun/2-2-sun-high-quality-png.png" alt="logo" width="80">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This one seems good. But any method without giving height to sun-half-wrapper?

Comment: @CssSY well i give height because you are using absolute position and also because you element need to be at the bottom unless you cannot see the element go upper :) .. but we can rely on margin also, am gonna update

Comment: @CssSY added another way you can have a look

Comment: New fix is also good but I need to position my image using absolute position.

Comment: if you need to position the image absolute, it should be relative to it's container and if there is no height you cannot set it to bottom unless you use negative value but it's not good .. so you can try the first example with negative value for bottom

Comment: I'll try on that. Thanks!

Comment: Good answer. For a modern (and of course with few support) way to do this, take a look here https://codepen.io/ruslan_khomiak/pen/RoMRjR